# Autodesk forge viewer, react+typescript Extensions

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am just starting with React and Typescript and I have a question, very basic may be...
In the viewer documentation, extensions are defined as classes, is it possible to transform that class into a typescript function? does it make any sense?
for example this simple class extension:

```
export class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
   load() {
     console.log('MyExtension has been loaded');
     return true;
   }
 
   unload() {
     console.log('MyExtension has been unloaded');
     return true;
   }
 
   static register() {
     Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
       "MyExtension",
       MyExtension
     );
   }
 };
```

How should it be as a function?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for this topic and only found it in context of **React Class Components** being turned into **React Functional Components**

A **Viewer** extension is not a **React** component, so not sure this technique could be applied.

Also, if you look in the [source code](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js) of the **Viewer** you'll see that when loading the extension, `loadExtensionLocal` will try to create a new instance of the extension class. So it seems like the extension needs to be a **class**.